# To Handle zoom control of MapController

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to save last zoom level of the map. Therefore I need to handle the zoomLevel of mapview. 
I coded  like below. But I am not sure this is a good solution. I could not implement to onDestroy, because, when back button was pressed, the zoom level settled by old value.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    config.setZoomLevel(mapView.getZoomLevel());
    saveConfig(config);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: when zoomLevel was changed by MapController, I want to handle that value.